# How to multiply in several steps with PowerQuery?

Tags: excel, merge, vlookup, powerquery, m

I try to calculate across multiple columns and rows, based on sort of a Vlookup. I tried to do it by doing a multiple merge but I got stuck.

[image: Screenshot of the data]

To clarify the idea, I would like to multiply all percentages in the third column, based on the order in the other columns. Parent level 1 owns 40% in the target company, parent level 2 owns 80% of level 1, parent level 3 owns 100% of level 2,.. etc.

The sum should then be 1x1x1x1x0.8x0.4= 0.32. This concludes that Parent level 6 owns 32% in the target company.

Is there any way in doing this? All help is very much appreciated!

EDIT: A bit more difficult scenario. What would work to find out the ownership percentages of the different Parents?
[image]

Comment: It is unclear what the output would be for the bottom two rows, since they are the same Parent. Is each one of them supposed to show the [100% john + 10% target ] number or does James/John get 100% of John and James/Target get 10% target

Comment: How do you transform these relations to one row?  In that case it is possible to do different calculations with them. For example the output from above example:
Row 1: James, 100, John corp, 50, IKEA, 40, Target company
Row 2: Peter, 80, IKEA, 40, Target company
Row 3: James, 10 Target company

Basically that PowerQuery searches the match between two columns, and takes the percentage from the other column, and places them in the right order as one row.

Comment: If you have a different question, then please post that one instead. This one was confusing

Comment: @HugoTerpstra Can you clarify what the end result should look like? Is it a new column or a new table? What exactly should it look like for your examples?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I opened a new thread about it. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525478/transform-colums-in-rows-based-on-the-relation